# Using WPK for PowerShell GUI

Tags: user-interface, powershell

We have created some great PowerShell scripts. But as time goes by we have given the scripts to non programmers. So we decided it was time for a simple easy to understand GUI for the PowerShell.

I have watched the channel 9 videos by James Brundage. His videos do a great job of explaining Window, Stack-Panel, Doc-Panel, Grid, Labels, and Textboxes.
However there are over 60 controls in total.   Not knowing WPF does not help.

What I would like to do is be able to do the following:

Text Input
Dropdown List
RadioButton Group
Checkbox Group

I came up with an example that does the first three but with bugs.
The Radio control visually shows the first button selected, but when I pull the value for the group it is not correct.

I cannot find an example for the Checkbox.

Any tips would be appreciated.

Here is my test of WPK in PowerShell:

```
function TestGui {
    Import-Module WPK

    $SelectedRadio = "First"

    New-Window -Title "Test User Input" -WindowStartupLocation CenterScreen `
      -Width 400 -Height 300 -Show {

      New-Grid -Rows 32*, 32*, 32*, 32* -Columns 100, 1* {

        #create style to use on controls
        $createLblStyle = @{
            Margin = 5
            HorizontalAlignment = "right"
            VerticalAlignment = "center"
        } 

        #Label Text for this row
        New-TextBlock -Text "Pick fruit" `
          -Row 0 -Column 0 @createLblStyle

        # dropdown ( combo box)
        New-ComboBox -Name FruitList `
          -row 0 -column 1 @createLblStyle `
          -Items { "Apple", "Pear", "Peach" } -SelectedIndex 0

        #Label Text for this row
        New-TextBlock -Text "Pick number" `
            -Row 1 -Column 0 @createLblStyle

        # TextBox
        New-TextBox -Name TextInputName `
          -Row 1 -Column 1 @createLblStyle 

        #Label Text for this row
        New-TextBlock -Text "Get Text Input" `
          -Row 2 -Column 0 @createLblStyle        

        #Do three radio buttons for this row.
        New-StackPanel -Row 2 -Column 1 -Orientation Horizontal {
            New-RadioButton -Content "Pick first" `
                -GroupName Results -IsChecked $True -On_Click {
                    $SelectedRadio = "First"
                }

            New-RadioButton -Content "Pick two" `
                -GroupName Results  -On_Click {
                    $SelectedRadio = "Second"
                }

            New-RadioButton -Content "Pick three" `
                -GroupName Results   -On_Click {
                    $SelectedRadio = "Third"
                }
        }


        New-Button -Content "_Call PS Script" -Row 3 -Column 0 -Margin 3 -On_Click {
          $FruitList          = $window | Get-ChildControl FruitList
          $TextInputName      = $Window | Get-ChildControl TextInputName
          $Results            = $Window | Get-ChildControl Results

          $Window.Close()
          write-host "call PS script with: "
          write-host "DropDown => " $FruitList.SelectedValue
          write-host "TextBox => " $TextInputName.Text
          write-host "Radio => " $SelectedRadio
    }

        New-Button -Content "Cancel" -Row 3 -Column 1 -Margin 3 -On_Click {
          $Window.Close()
          write-host "Cancel was pressed"
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem with radio button ? I can't see any.

Comment: bernd, it's when I try to get the selected button back, it doesn't give me the one I have selected.

Comment: I tested all e cases initial state, middle, right, left radio button and 'Call PS Script' gives: Radio =>  First, Radio =>  First, Radio =>  Third, Radio =>  First. Did you get always the same value or did you get different, but wrong values?

Comment: I believe I was only getting the first value no matter what I checked. I'll have to revisit this code, as I used a drop list instead to get past the problem. Though I would like to have the ability to use radio's if I can.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you wants to create a GUI on the top of a PowerShell script you wrote.

My opinion is that you've got two technical solutions.

1. You build a GUI on the top of the Windows Form, which is the former way to build GUI in de .NET Framework
2. You build a GUI on the top of WPF, wich is a new way to build GUI in de .NET Framework

In the first solution you can directly create your form with visual studio and "[transform](http://www.powershell-scripting.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=217&Itemid=80)" it, or create it with a [Sapien](http://my.sapien.com) company tool called "[PrimalForms Community Edition](http://downloads.sapien.com/#Free%20tools/32%20Bit/PrimalFormsCE.exe)" wich is a free GUI builder tool for PowerShell users. You build your GUI (like a .NET developper) and the tool generate the Window Form code in PowerShell syntax. You just have to call your script function in the right place (the one generated for each event script block). This solution is ok for normal forms.

The WPF solution is a bit more recent and specialy dedicated for the case in which you want to add 2D or 3D graph in your forms or adaptation to different screen size. In this solution you have to build a XAML representation of your form (with visual studio 2010 Expess for example)and then load it into PowerShell. This solution need PowerShell 2.0 and Framework 3.5 installed plus special flags (-STA) to start PowerShell. For me the WPK module is buid on this solution.

It exists also a way to create charts in PowerShell.

If your are interested in one or other solution, please let me know.

I hope it help.

JP

Comment: JP, 
 I am trying specifically to do this using the PowerShellPack (WPK) and not by creating a windows form. ex:Run a script that opens a little window for some simple inputs. With a button that calls more script to use the input provided. I can make it work with New-TextBox / New-ComboBox(by manually adding items) but am still trying to find syntax examples for New-RadioButton(List)/New-CheckBox(List) and possibly a ListBox instead of ComboBox.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `$Script:SelectedRadio` in `On_Click` scriptblocks of radiobuttons.

Answer (score 0):

To find out which of your three Radio Buttons has been checked, you could use the following expression:

```
if ( ($Window | Get-ChildControl 'One' ).IsChecked ) {
   $SelectedRadioButton = '1'
} elseif ( ($Window | Get-ChildControl 'Two' ).IsChecked ) {
   $SelectedRadioButton = '2'
} elseif ( ($Window | Get-ChildControl 'Three' ).IsChecked) {
   $SelectedRadioButton = '3'
}
```

If you have just one group of radio buttons, there is no need to assign a group name. There is also no need for an On_Click event. You could shorten your New-RadioButton expressions to:

```
New-RadioButton -Name 'One'   -Content "Pick first" -IsChecked $true
New-RadioButton -Name 'Two'   -Content "Pick two"
New-RadioButton -Name 'Three' -Content "Pick three"
```

To find out, whether a Check Box:

```
New-CheckBox -Name 'Uno' -Content "Uno"
```

has been checked, you would also infer its IsChecked property:

```
Write-Host "Checkbox UNo => " ($Window | Get-ChildControl UNo).IsChecked
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out an existing module from PSGallery.

It's been a while since I had a look at such modules myself

- [AnyBox](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AnyBox)
- [WinFormPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinFormPS)
- [FormsBuilder](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FormsBuilder)
- [Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleGuiTools)
- [PSScriptMenuGui](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSScriptMenuGui)
- [WinGUI](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinGUI)
- [PSLauncher](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSLauncher)
- [WPFPS](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WPFPS)
- [PSWebGui](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWebGui)
- [FormsBuilder](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/FormsBuilder)

But most anything beats messing with WinForm or WPF by hand :)